# Battery Information on Raspberry Pi

Tags: battery, power-management, laptop, ups

I am currently using [PiSugar 2 Pro](https://github.com/PiSugar/PiSugar/wiki/PiSugar2-Pro) for my Raspberry Pi 3B+. While I know that PiSugar has its own server where you can check on battery level, I was looking for a more direct integration with the OS, such as the one that laptops have that allow them to display the battery widget and display information via `upower`. My battery is not being listed in `/sys/class/power_supply/` and because of that I can't use the traditional tools like `acpi`, etc.

Does anyone know what I would need to enable this? The PiSugar provides information via [I2C](https://github.com/PiSugar/PiSugar/wiki/PiSugar-2-(Pro)-I2C-Manual).

I am using the latest Raspberry Pi OS:

```
Release date: April 4th 2022
System: 64-bit
Kernel version: 5.15
Debian version: 11 (bullseye)
```